# Custom Url on opencart

Tags: php, opencart

now i'm doing some project with opencart platform. i want to know, do we able to custom the url?

as i know, if we want to put other information on url. the format will be like this

```
https://random.com/index.php?route=api/seller/order&seller_id=123
```

is there any posible to custom the url like this

```
https://random.com/index.php?route=api/seller/<seller_id>/order
 
example : https://random.com/index.php?route=api/seller/123/order
```

the seller_id will be dynamic and if it posible, how do i can get the seller_id from the controller?

please help

Comment: yes, possible, by creating your own router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache mod_rewrite to modify URL

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} route=api/seller/(\d+)/order
RewriteRule ^index.php index.php?route=api/seller/order&order_id=%1 [L]
```

`http://random.com/index.php?route=api/seller/123/order`
will turn into
`http://random.com/index.php?route=api/seller/order&order_id=123`